# JavaScript group similar objects by same value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, I need to group them by the same value, I need to group them by a multidimensional array

```
const source = [
                 {name: 'A', age: 23, id: 0}, 
                 {name: 'A', age: 23, id: 1},
                 {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 34}, 
                 {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 45},
                 {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 32},
                 {name: 'C', age: 15, id: 32},
               ];


[
```

Like this structure, all the same objects should be grouped by array inside an array.

```
  [
   {name: 'A', age: 23, id: 0}, 
   {name: 'A', age: 23, id: 1}
  ],
  [
   {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 34}, 
   {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 45},
   {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 32}
  ],
  [
   {name: 'C', age: 15, id: 32},
  ]
]
```

I have tried like this but no luck.

```
const result = source.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
    if (accumulator && accumulator.length) {
      const found = accumulator.find(group => {
        return group && group.length
          ? group.find(_transaction =>
              // check the same object 
              return false
            )
          : false;
      });
      if (found) {

        console.log(found);
      }
    } else {
      accumulator.push([item]);
    }

    return accumulator;
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object indexed by the `name` property, whose values are arrays containing the `source` items, then take the object's values:

```js
const source = [
 {name: 'A', age: 23, id: 0}, 
 {name: 'A', age: 23, id: 1},
 {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 34}, 
 {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 45},
 {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 32},
 {name: 'C', age: 15, id: 32},
];
const sourceItemsByName = {};
for (const obj of source) {
  if (!sourceItemsByName[obj.name]) {
    sourceItemsByName[obj.name] = [];
  }
  sourceItemsByName[obj.name].push(obj);
}
const output = Object.values(sourceItemsByName);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the group array and if found add the object or add a new group to the result set.

```js
const
    source = [{ name: 'A', age: 23, id: 0 }, { name: 'A', age: 23, id: 1 }, { name: 'B', age: 15, id: 34 }, { name: 'B', age: 15, id: 45 }, { name: 'B', age: 15, id: 32 }, { name: 'C', age: 15, id: 32 }],
    groups = ['name', 'age'],
    grouped = source.reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = r.find(([q]) => groups.every(k => o[k] === q[k]));
        if (temp) {
            temp.push(o);
        } else {
            r.push([o]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An approach with a `Map`

```js
const
    source = [{ name: 'A', age: 23, id: 0 }, { name: 'A', age: 23, id: 1 }, { name: 'B', age: 15, id: 34 }, { name: 'B', age: 15, id: 45 }, { name: 'B', age: 15, id: 32 }, { name: 'C', age: 15, id: 32 }],
    groups = ['name', 'age'],
    grouped = Array.from(source
        .reduce(
            (m, o) => 
                (k => m.set(k, [...(m.get(k) || []), o]))
                (groups.map(k => o[k]).join('|')),
            new Map)
        .values()
    );

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks @ Nina Scholz, but i need to match 2 props not only the `name`. `name` and `age`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the array to a Map, using the `name` and `age` combination as the key. Then spread the `Map.values()` iterator back to an array:

```js
const source = [{ name: 'A', age: 23, id: 0 }, { name: 'A', age: 23, id: 1 }, { name: 'B', age: 15, id: 34 }, { name: 'B', age: 15, id: 45 }, { name: 'B', age: 15, id: 32 }, { name: 'C', age: 15, id: 32 }];

const result = [... // spread the values iterator to an array
  source.reduce((r, o) => {
    const key = `${o.name}---${o.age}`; // generate a key with name and age
    if(!r.has(key)) r.set(key, []); // add a new entry for key if it's not in the Map

    r.get(key).push(o); // push the current object to the keys's entry

    return r;
  }, new Map())
  .values() // get the Maps values iterator
];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code is easier to understand. Hope, it will help you. Thanks.

**UPDATED:** As you need mentioned in a comment that you need `name` and `age` property as your key value.

```js
const source = [
 {name: 'A', age: 23, id: 0}, 
 {name: 'A', age: 23, id: 1},
 {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 34}, 
 {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 45},
 {name: 'B', age: 15, id: 32},
 {name: 'C', age: 15, id: 32},
];

var hashObject = {}

source.forEach(function(elem) {
  var key = elem.name + elem.age;
  if (hashObject[key]) {
    hashObject[key].push(elem);
  } else {
    hashObject[key] = [elem];
  }
});

var desiredArray = Object.values(hashObject);

console.log(desiredArray);
```